# How to display data from the server into a recycler view in android

Tags: android

I don't have code. Just need suggestions on this. 
I am currently creating an Android app (self learning, completely new to this). I would like to display data from the server (perform GET request) in a recycler view on my app. I've read about `RecyclerView, Adapter, ViewModel, Holder, AsyncTask` but I'm having troubles glueing everything together. I would like to make my architecture as extensible and clean as possible. Any suggestions or links would do. I've gone through several resources online but nothing that fully covers this topic as a whole.

Comment: You can look at my [project](https://github.com/kasimoz/Exchange_Android)

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir thank you! I'm coding my project in java but I've gathered a clearer picture after looking at your project structure. may I know what's the difference between the ViewModel and SharedViewModel classes?

Comment: Shared ViewModel is shared between Fragments for example. Btw. don't use AsyncTasks, use Handlers or Coroutines (if You use Kotlin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the next medium tutorial about Clean Architecture on Android and the example fetching data from the server to populate a recycler view 
https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-implement-a-clean-architecture-on-android-2e5e8c8e81fe

The idea is to create layers with different responsibilities:
UI + Presenter (prepare data to show in the UI) + Domain (Business logic) + Repository (flow to fetch data)